# Настроить кроссдоменный ajax запрос

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

Добрый день! Никак не могу настроить кроссдоменный `ajax` запрос. Помогите, пожалуйста.

На одном домене есть форма, которая отправляет запрос на другой домен. Другой должен прислать ответ: либо `{"error":1}`, либо `{"error":0}`. В зависимости от этого функция ответа указанная в `jsonpCallback`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://site/sendmail.html',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {
        'name' : jQuery('#name').val(),
            'email' : jQuery('#email').val(),
            'phonecode' : jQuery('#phonecode').val(),
            'phonenumber' : jQuery('#phonenumber').val(),
            'message' : jQuery('#message').val()
    },
    jsonpCallback: "mailResponce"

    });

    function mailResponce(responce) {
    if(responce.error < 1){
                    alert('Запрос отправлен!');
            }else{
                    alert('Ошибка при отправлении запроса!');
                }
}
```

После отправки запроса приходит ответ:
http://site.ru/sendmail.html?callback=mailResponce&name=Vasea&email=mail@40yandex.ru

Мне же, как я понимаю, чтоб сработала функция `jsonpCallback: "mailResponce"`, в ответе должно быть .. html?callback=mailResponce{"error":0}&...
Для этого мне нужно что-то как-то специально передавать с сервера который посылает ответ?
Сейчас сервер выдает: `echo json_encode($data);`
либо `$data['error'] = 0;` либо `$data['error'] = 1;`
но в `callback` функции это не передается.

Подскажите, что я не так делаю! Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Кроссдоменный запрос - это по сути загрузка скрипта. Вы загружаете скрипт, срабатывает событие onload на этотй скрипт и выполняется функция, которая указана как "jsonpCallback".

Answer (score 1):

http://site.ru/sendmail.html?callback=mailResponce&name=Vasea&email=mail@40yandex.ru - это не ответ. Это и есть тот самый запрос, который вы отправили.

Чтобы сработала функция mailResponce, надо, чтобы в *ответе* она была вызвана. Пример корректного `jsonp`-ответа, который мог бы выдать сервер:

```
mailResponce({ error : 0})
```

Как такой ответ получить, думайте уже сами, я `php` не знаю.

---

PS Но задумайтесь: что же вы делаете?! Вы даете любому желающему способ отправлять безо всякой авторизации любую почту на любой электронный адрес! Как вы думаете, как много времени пройдет, прежде чем ваш "сервис" начнет использоваться спамерами?

Answer (score -1):

Можно:

Есть небольшой трюк с PHP. И этот трюк будет работать не только с Google, но и с любыми сайтами, к которым у вас нет доступа и вы не можете добавить Access-Control-Allow-Origin *

Нам нужно создать PHP-файл (например. getContentFromUrl.php) на нашем сервере и сделать обращение к нему.

**PHP**

```
<?php

$ext_url = $_POST['ext_url'];

echo file_get_contents($ext_url);

?>
```

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'getContentFromUrl.php', // link to your PHP file
    data: {
        // url куда наш сервер будет отправлять запрос, который мы не можем сделать через AJAX
        'ext_url': 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114436/access-control-allow-origin-error-sending-a-jquery-post-to-google-apis'
    },
    success: function(data) {
        // теперь мы можем взять любые данные из внешнего url, потому что у нас есть вся страница
        var $h1 = $(data).find('h1').html();

        $('h1').text($h1);
    },
    error:function() {
        console.log('Error');
    }
});
```

**Как это работает:**

1. Ваш браузер с помощью JS отправит запрос на ваш сервер
2. Ваш сервер отправит запрос на любой другой сервер и получит ответ
3. Ваш сервер отправит этот ответ в ваг JS файл

И мы можем добавить event типа onClick на кнопку. Надеюсь, это поможет!

Answer (score -2):

Сервер который вам отвечает, должен дополнительно передавать заголовок **Access-Control-Allow-Origin:your-domain.ru** или так **Access-Control-Allow-Origin:***

Тобишь отвечающий сервер, должен явно указать браузеру, что вам можно получать его ответы.

Comment: тут jsonp. это не аякс, не xmlhttprequest.